solana-program-test fails to serialize account when an optional field is started from None instead of Some
When testing an instruction, I manually set the field of my accounts. The account serialization fails (code: 3004) when a specific field is set to None (which is totally fine by my own program logic) bet runs fine when set to Some(x). This might reveal an issue with how the solana-program-test serializes accounts or when it calculates their size. Manually increasing the size I have specified for my account does not fix the issue. I have tested the exact scenario with TS solana-test-validator and it works there. SecretHitler repo
here is my code:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use secret_hitler::{
    enums::{GameState, PlayerCount},
    id,
    state::GameData,
};
use solana_program_test::*;
use solana_sdk::{
    account::AccountSharedData,
    native_token::LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    signature::{Keypair, Signer},
    transaction::Transaction,
};

mod utils;
use utils::*;

mod instructions;
use instructions::*;

#[tokio::test]
async fn test_eliminate_player() {
    let mut program_test = ProgramTest::new("secret_hitler", id(), None);
    program_test.set_compute_max_units(200_000);

    let host = Keypair::new();

    airdrop(&mut program_test, host.pubkey(), 10 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);

    // Process the instruction
    let mut context = program_test.start_with_context().await;

    // Generate game PDA
    let (game_pubkey, game_bump) = get_game_data_address(host.pubkey());

    // Create initial game state
    let mut all_players = vec![Keypair::new().pubkey(); 4];
    all_players.push(host.pubkey());

    let clock = context.banks_client.get_sysvar::<Clock>().await.unwrap();
    let current_time = clock.unix_timestamp;

    let game_struct: GameData = GameData {
        host: host.pubkey(),
        turn_duration: 100,
        max_players: 5,
        entry_deposit: None,
        bet_amount: None,
        start_player_count: Some(PlayerCount::Five),
        all_starting_players: all_players.clone(),

        active_players: all_players,
        eliminated_players: vec![],
        turn_started_at: Some(current_time),
        game_state: GameState::ChancellorNomination,
        fascist_policies_enacted: 0,
        liberal_policies_enacted: 0,
        failed_elections: 0,
        is_special_election: false,
        current_president_index: 4,
        previous_president_index: None, //  Panics when tested with None
        current_chancellor_index: None,
        previous_chancellor_index: None,
        bump: game_bump,
        deposit_vault_bump: None,
        bet_vault_bump: None,
    };

    let mut game_account_data = vec![];
    game_struct.try_serialize(&mut game_account_data).unwrap();

    let mut account = AccountSharedData::new(u32::MAX as u64, GameData::INIT_SPACE, &id());
    account.set_data_from_slice(&game_account_data);

    context.set_account(&game_pubkey, &account);

    forward_time(&mut context, 150).await;

    // Execute take instruction
    let mut transaction = Transaction::new_with_payer(
        &[eliminate_player(&host.pubkey(), &game_pubkey, None)],
        Some(&context.payer.pubkey()),
    );

    transaction.sign(&[&context.payer, &host], context.last_blockhash);
    let result = context.banks_client.process_transaction(transaction).await;
    assert!(result.is_ok(), "Failed {:?}", result);
}


The error makes sense. You're initializing the account by just setting its account data directly into solana-program-test. Anchor uses Borsh serialization by default, and Borsh serializes a None value to just a 0, and serializes a Some to 1 plus all of the data. This means that your account will not have enough room if that None ever becomes a Some.
To get around this, you can overallocate a buffer before writing the data in if you change the buffer initialization to:
    let mut game_account_data = vec![0; GameData::INIT_SPACE];


I appreciate your answer. But over allocating more space in the vector does not fix the issue unfortunately.
